# I am getting a syntax error when hashing passwords

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have built a site which hashes passwords for new users. The site worked and the passwords hashed. Xampp crashed and I had to reinstall and I now get a syntax error when I try to register a new user. I have not changed the code, the error is:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')' in
> C:\Users\chris\OneDrive\Desktop\XAMPP\htdocs\irnMind\register-process.php
> on line 67

Line 67 is -  `$hash = password_hash($pwd, algo: PASSWORD_BCRYPT);`

```
$checkUser ="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$user'";
$result = $conn->query($checkUser);

if($result->num_rows > 0){
        header('Location: register.php?error=usernametaken');
    
}else{
    $hash = password_hash($pwd, algo: PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, firstname, lastname, email, mobile,
                                age, maingoal, likes, dislike, available, 
                                pwd, profilepicture ) 
            VALUES ('$user', '$first', '$last', '$email', '$mobile', 
                    '$age', '$goal', '$fav', '$dislike', '$available', 
                    '$hash', '$target_file')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo '<div>';
        echo '<p>' . "Your account has been registered. Please click Login to proceed to your account. Thank you." . '</p>';
        echo '</div>';
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
}


$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Named parameters will work since PHP 8.0

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the doc where you need to add `algo:` into the code. I certainly don't do that when I use `password_hash()`.

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: We have to assume you are not using PHP8

Comment: I deleted algo: and this fixed the problem. I'm new to this malarky. Thanks Droopsnoot.